# Merge two React applications into one

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

Im trying to combine two existing React apps. The first one is the regular one, without router, so the index.ts file
renders :

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

the second one is React DnD with router and its index.ts file is :

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
    <AppStateProvider>
      <App />
    </AppStateProvider>
  </DndProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

in my App.tsx file i decide what content to render (does user requests the first or the second app), so im not sure how to isolate the provider from app
if i don't need it.

Comment: You can have 2 buttons with one button for your first app and 2nd button containing a link to the other app. You could redirect those url's accordingly using services like Docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the final render to DOM inn App.tsx and create two component, with and without Provider and select the one that you need and render it

index.ts

```
const AppWithProvider = () => (
   <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
    <AppStateProvider>
      <App />
    </AppStateProvider>
  </DndProvider>
)
export default AppWithProvider;
```

App.tsx

```
import AppWithProvider from '/your/provider/path';
import App from '/your/app/path';
const Comp = yourConditionForProvider? AppWithProvider: App;
ReactDOM.render(
  <Comp />,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```